# bash shell script error: ambigious redirect

Tags: arrays, bash, function, shell, mips

In the following code, a problem occurs when encapsulating the block of code with a function. The error message `$1: ambigious redirect" is displayed.`

The `while` loop reads text from the `input.txt` file line by line and stores it in the array `linesArray`.

The `for` loop within the 'while' loop iterates through all the elements of the `linesArray` array at index 0, and then executes the case-statement, which compares the elements of the array with valid mips operators.

```
function mnemonicCheck {
  while read line; do
    linesArray=($line)
    for e in ${linesArray[0]}
    do  
      case $e in
        "add")
        ;;
        "sub")
        ;;
        "addi")
        ;;
        "lw")
        ;;
        "sw")
        ;;
        *)
        echo "invalid operator used. Valid operators are: add,sub,addi,lw,sw"
        ;;
      esac
    done
  done < $1
}

#calling methods
checkArguments $1 $2 $3
mnemonicCheck
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `mnemonicCheck` without any arguments, so inside the function `$1` is the empty string.

What would you then expect

```
< $1
```

to mean? (I agree that "ambiguous" is an odd word to use in this context, but it's not entirely incorrect since one cannot say for certain what is meant.)

Comment: the $1 refers to the argument for the while loop, which reads the text of a file.

Comment: @user2037720: No, it doesn't. A while loop doesn't have arguments. $1 always means the first function/script argument.

Comment: @user2037720: If you meant that `$1` is used to redirect stdin for the while loop, you would be correct. But where does it get a value from?

Comment: Change `< $1` to `< input.txt`

Comment: i've fixed it thanks. what I did was assigned input.txt to a variable, and then replaced it with $1.